# PHP variables and memory leaking

Tags: php, performance, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is it possible to create memory leaks when coding in PHP?

I seem to be getting really slow performance when iterating through large loop constructs.

Should i unset() the variables that im not using?

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: Can you even be certain that memory leaks is the problem, and not simply inefficient code?

Comment: In the loop use the same variable for every instance. If you are refering to `constructs` as class instantiation, use singleton or instantiate a class above the loop. Usually the problem is the code.

Comment: I will try and formulate a code example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a garbage collector (although as of PHP 5.3 it does). It uses reference counting to manage memory. Thus, the most common source of memory leaks are cyclic references and global variables.

The simplest instrument is to selectively place calls to memory_get_usage and narrow it down to where the code leaks. You can also use xdebug to create a trace of the code.

Run the code with execution traces and show_mem_delta.

to read more about garbage collection in PHP 5.3+ see [php.net/manual/de/features.gc.php](http://php.net/manual/de/features.gc.php)

**PHP 5.3 +**

in PHP 5.3+ there is the ability to perform garbage collection at three major places (there are others):

**1.When you tell it to.** like using unset() or mysql_free_result()

**2.When you leave a function** clearing any variable that leaves scope

**3.When the script ends** ...pretty obvious

Comment: Very thorough example thank you for putting in the time to make your edits.

Answer (score 0):

**If PHP itself works without bugs, then it is not possible that memory leaks can happen in a php script.**

Memory cleanup is done by the [PHP garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) for you. While it in most cases will work well without any effort of the programmer it can be controlled using a set of functions.  [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have memory-leaks in Php,
A basic way to see if you have memory leak in O(n) loop is to see if your loop time is proportional to he number of object, for instance 100 object is about 10 times longer than a loop for 10 object. If the loop is way longer for 100 objects you probably have memory leak.

Comment: You've quoted the php dev guide for extension developers. Extensions are written in C. The question was about PHP code

Answer (score 0):

From php 5.3 the garbage collector can detect cyclic reference, see https://www.php.net/gc_enable

you can force a collecting cycle by using :
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

All of these function have a big cost, so use it with precaution, and in most case let php doing this for you, it's his job :)